# Forcing TinyMCE to be the same height as parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tinymce-4

Just to help you understand my problem I created this pen to display the issue I am having: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZwvQz

As you can see when I set the height of the TinyMce to 700px it goes past the parent div, I just want TinyMce to be pushed to fit the parent div. I found that TinyMce does not support percentages on the height. Is there anyway I can do this, plus stop any resizing past the parent div that TinyMce is in?

Here is my HTML:

```
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#codeNotesEditor'
  });
</script>
<main>
<div id="myClippetWrapper">

  <div id="clippetNav">



  </div>

  <div id="codeAndNotesWrapper">

    <div id="codeView">

    </div>

    <div id="noteView">

      <textarea id="codeNotesEditor"></textarea>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

  </main>
```

My CSS:

```
main
{
  padding: 20px;
}

#myClippetWrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 700px;
}

#clippetNav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #222222;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#codeAndNotesWrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#codeAndNotesWrapper>div {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

#codeView {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #222222;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#noteView {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #222222;
}

#codeNotesEditor {}
```

JS:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  menubar: false,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
  ],
  toolbar: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
  content_css: '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css',
  height: 700
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible!

As TinyMCE is dynamically generated, it attaches to the `element` directly as an inline style. This means that you cannot target it with higher specificity, but fortunately you can use `!important` instead to override the rules. You also won't know the name of the DIV created by TinyMCE, so you'll have to take the direct descendant of `#noteView`:

```
#noteView > div {
  height: 100% !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

It's important to give it both a height that correlates to the height of the container, but to **also** hide the overflow, so that it doesn't go past the bottom of the container.

I've created a working fiddle showcasing this [here](http://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/OpMEdm).

Hope this helps! :)